Reference request for the determinant of a matrix constructed from Pascal's triangle
One can prove by induction that the matrix $M^{(n)}$ given by
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & \binom{n}{0} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & \binom{n+1}{1} \\
1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & \dots & \binom{n+2}{2} \\
1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & \dots & \binom{n+3}{3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\binom{n}{0} & \binom{n+1}{1} & \binom{n+2}{2} & \binom{n+3}{3} & \dots & \binom{2n}{n}
\end{pmatrix} $$
and which can be viewed as a truncation of Pascal's triangle "on its side." has determinant one. It seems likely that this is a known result, but so far I have not been able to find a reference. I would like add a citation if it indeed is a known result, hence the reference request.

Look here Edelman, A., & Strang, G. (2004). Pascal Matrices. The American Mathematical Monthly, 111(3), 189–197. https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2004.11920065

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix

@BenjaminSteinberg Thanks!
